# Is there a way to display none on scroll and on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm setting up an 'about' section that closes when scrolled more than 65px and opens when above that, which works, although I would like a way I can also click on the arrow to close/show no matter the height. Thanks!

I can get the section to open/close on click, and then do the same with scroll, but cannot get it to do both

```js
let toggleAboutStatus = false;
window.onscroll = function() {
  toggleAbout()
}
let toggleAbout = function() {

  let getAboutP = document.querySelector(".about p");
  let getAboutIcon = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle-about");

  if (document.body.scrollTop > 65 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 65) {
    getAboutIcon.style.backgroundPosition = "center bottom";
    getAboutIcon.style.transform = "rotateZ(0deg)"
    getAboutP.style.display = "none";

    toggleAboutStatus = true;
  } else if (toggleAboutStatus === true) {
    getAboutIcon.style.backgroundPosition = "center top";
    getAboutIcon.style.transform = "rotateZ(180deg)";
    getAboutP.style.display = "block";

    toggleAboutStatus = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.about {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(65, 60, 60, 0.021), rgba(65, 60, 60, 0.466));
}

.about p {
  margin: 10px 20px 0px;
  display: block;
}

.btn-toggle-about {
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url(img/icons/arrow-icon.png);
  background-size: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.pageup {
  height: 100px;
}

.pagedown {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageup"></div>

<section class="about">
  <p>Welcome to our website! Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, alias!</p>
  <div class="btn-toggle-about" onclick="toggleAbout()"></div>
</section>

<div class="pagedown"></div>
```

So in conclusion I expect the function 'toggleAbout' to display none on scroll past 65, but can still click the .btn-toggle-about to have it run function 'toggleAbout' also.

Comment: Not possible with your current HTML structure. Also you shouldn't use inline styles; instead, put those styles into CSS classes and work with element.classList.add/remove/toggle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How would I set up a correct HTML structure to support this? I'm brand new to coding so learning as I go hahah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, Maybe I think you want this. You can use jQuery if you want. And also modify it as per your need.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var sticky = $('.about'),
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 65) sticky.addClass('hide');
  else sticky.removeClass('hide');
});

$('.btn-toggle-about').click(function() {
  $('.about').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.about {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(65, 60, 60, 0.021), rgba(65, 60, 60, 0.466));
}

.about p {
  margin: 10px 20px 0px;
  display: block;
}

.btn-toggle-about {
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url(img/icons/arrow-icon.png);
  background-size: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.pageup {
  height: 100px;
}

.pagedown {
  height: 1000px;
}

.about.hide p {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pageup"></div>

<section class="about">
  <p>Welcome to our website! Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, alias!</p>
  <div class="btn-toggle-about"></div>
</section>

<div class="pagedown"></div>
```

Comment: YES! With a bit tweaking I can make this do exactly as I want. Thanks so much!!